# Android: Bottom sheet with intent chooser to share data

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically what I want is this:

[image: Screenshot of intent chooser bottom sheet]

I have read about modal bottom sheets for quite a while but I haven't found any solution till now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [BottomSheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet)?

Comment: @AkashPatel I always avoid 3rd party libraries since you risk getting no support on stackoverflow or from the developer

Comment: This share action is different per device, os and manufacturer.

Comment: @AkashPatel any guidelines or resources to make the standard chooser dialog material?

Comment: Did you ever get around to a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that Android has [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html) which is part of AppCompatDialog library. I haven't implemented any of this in my app, so I'm not sure about the properties and behaviour. Probably, it is same with normal DialogFragment. You will be able to inflate your own layout, in this case RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager to achieve above design. You can check on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295#.xah645iju) for reference.

Ref: [Moving from Dialogs to BottomSheetDialogs on Android](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295#.xah645iju)

Comment: Saw a lot of similar tutorials but I can't understand how would I inflate the chooser view! The apps that qualify to service the intent are known only at runtime

Answer (score -1):

You can now use Official BottomSheetBehavior API from android support library 23.2.

You can check below link for better idea,
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/modal-bottom-sheet-with-material-design.html

Also refer to [Android BottomSheet youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAgKp-BYv1I) to get understanding on it.